# Are Mandeans considered Ahl-ul Kitab?

Tags: ahlul-kitab

It seems there are different of opinions whether Mandeans just are the Sabians, or another group. Quoting wikipedia:

> Many scholars have identified the Sabians to be the Mandaeans
>
> [Sabians in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabians)

**Question:** Are Mandeans considered Ahl-ul Kitab?

Comment: Can you edit your question to say that you want scholarly opinions?

Comment: Yes I could but wouldn't categorizing a group to be considered ahlu al Kitab, by default only accept scholarly opinion?

Comment: If what you are saying is right, then my answer would be of scholarly opinion as the caliphs would have been scholars.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I research, I concluded (based on my observation) that: firstly, Mandaeans is another name for Sabians secondly, as you yourself mentioned in your query, apparently there are diverse viewpoint regarding them if they are Ahlul-Ketab or not. Namely, a number of scholars don't consider them as Ahlul-Ketab, but there are other scholars who regard them as Ahlul-Ketab.
For instance, based on my research, I found that:

**Ayatollah Khamenei as a famous Shia scholar/Marja'al-Taqlid consider
 them as Ahlul-Ketab.**

---

As some related informative issue concerning them:

> they have a book called Suhuf Adam (Books of Adam) and Ginza Rba. They
>   believe that the prophet John (Yahya) conveyed the book to them 2000
>   years ago in its current form as a transmission from earlier prophets,
>   Adam (a), Noah (a), and Seth (a). The Quran has addressed them along
>   with the Jews and the Nazarites as People of the Book and believers in
>   God. However, there are doubts about whether today's Sabi'un, who are
>   also called Mughassila and Mandaeans and live in southwestern parts of
>   Iran and southeastern parts of Iraq around Tigris and Karkheh rivers,
>   are the same as the ones referred to in the Quran.
>
> And so forth.

---

For further information, you can refer to the following source:

- http://en.wikishia.net/view/People_of_the_Book